# Should I use singleton pattern in php

Tags: php, design-patterns, singleton

I am currently working on an application, and I wanted to implement a singleton class. But someone told me singleton in PHP is not really a singleton.

Is this true? What does it mean? And what should I do in that case?

Comment: PHP isn't special. the syntax might be different, but a singleton is just a singleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Singleton is a design pattern. It isn't really language specific. If a language is object orientated, then it can usually implement singletons, and PHP is certainly no exception.

There is an argument, however, that singletons aren't very conducive to an object orientated approach to software development. You may want to consider using Dependency Injection, instead?

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html which describes in better detail a number of popular patterns and how to do them in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Of course, if application architecture needs singleton, you must use it.

Answer (score 0):

A singleton pattern(single instance of a given class) is not bad to use it.
 As all the patterns,you have to know when is good to use it and when is bad.
Also the singleton pattern is not recommended when you are using multi threads.

On php is common use Dependency injection with Composer for third party libraries

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for the same in php

https://github.com/domnikl/DesignPatternsPHP/blob/master/Singleton/Singleton.php